# Eclipse library

Tags: java, eclipse, list

there are two types of data that can be easly mixed up by the compiler.
Here they're:

```
java.util.List
```

and

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List
```

I need both in a method I have created and the only workaround I have found is to use the absolute path in the declaration section, at least for one of those types.
I.e: `java.util.List<String> listofstring;`

Any hints?

Comment: No hints. That's how it's done :)

Comment: Why "compiler-construction"? This is basic Java. You can't import a class with the same local name twice, you have to use a fully-qualified name. So there's no other way.

Comment: I would suggest importing neither class, and using the fully qualified name for both. Otherwise you may confuse yourself, or more likely the person who looks at your code in 6 months time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java Language Specification, there is no workaround (except for a type parameter what would not be a very good idea).

[§7.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) is the section about import declaration: an imported type is being refereed to by its simple name :

> A single-type-import declaration (§7.5.1) imports a single named type,
>   by mentioning its canonical name

The scope of the import is the importing type - [§6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible

You should not have two same simple names because of shadowing - [§6.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4):

> Some declarations are not permitted within the scope of a local
>   variable, formal parameter, exception parameter, or local class
>   declaration because it would be impossible to distinguish between the
>   declared entities using only simple names.